# Style-Loader useable feature won't work in Webpack 2.x

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, webpack-style-loader

I'm using Webpack `^2.2.1` and the Style-Loader `^0.13.2`.

The rule for .css files from my Webpack config looks like:

```
            {
                test:       /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    { loader: 'style-loader', options: { useable: true } },
                    { loader: 'css-loader' }
                ]
            }
```

Now when I asynchronously `import` (former `require.ensure`, `System.import`) a css file, you were receiving an object instead the raw css data, with methods attached to it: `use()` and `unuse()` (because, the `useable` option is set to `true`).

```
    import( './mod1.css' ).then( cssRaw => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            // let's assume an async use case
            cssRaw.use();
        },3000);
    });
```

However, this won't work any more for me (`Uncaught TypeError: cssRaw.use is not a function`).

In fact, the object that `import` (former `System.import`) provides here, does not own such methods.

**Is there anything I'm doing wrong here or did anything change in Webpack 2.x?**
This exact code worked properly beforehand.

---

As it was mentioned in the answers so far, passing over the loader-string as

```
{ loader: 'style-loader/useable' }
```

work just as expected. If that is the supposed way to go, I guess the "*[recommended configuration for style-loader in 2.x](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/style-loader/#recommended-configuration)*" is pretty wrong.

---

I submitted an issue on the Webpack github page which was accepted was fixed today (https://github.com/webpack-contrib/style-loader/pull/185/commits).

Answer (score 4):

Change your loader configuration to the following:

```
{
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: [
        { loader: 'style-loader/useable' },
        { loader: 'css-loader' }
    ]
}
```

**Useable** seems to not be an option, but a loader in itself, available within the style-loader module directory.

Comment: You are right, it works if we pass over the loader-string as you described. In this case, I got pretty hard trolled by the official "*Webpack style-loader guide for 2.x*" (https://webpack.js.org/loaders/style-loader/#recommended-configuration) which explicitly describes the `useable` feature as option.

Comment: Unfoortunately, Webpack documentation is definitely not known for being up to date nor correct in many cases.